# How to slice all elements in a list to a certain length

Tags: python, list

Assuming I have a list with multiple strings in there.

```
x = ["red", "green", "black", "orange", "purple"]
```

I want to slice every element in the list to a certain length, eg. 4 characters. Then the list should look like this:

```
x = ["red", "gree", "blac", "oran", "purp"]
```

I tried it with x[0:4], but doing so only sliced the list to 4 elements like

```
x = ["red", "gree", "blac", "oran"]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: There is no GIS component to this pure Python question so I think it should be researched/asked at [so] rather than here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `x[0:4]` you are accessing the list's items, not the list items' items. This will work:

```
x = ["red", "green", "black", "orange", "purple"]
for index, item in enumerate(x):
    x[index] = x[index][0:4]
```